# Failing to see the difference between these two lines of thought in dynamic programming

Tags: dynamic-programming

Always there are multiple ways people describe differences in tabulation and memoization in dynamic programming, but I will summarize to what is normally said.

1. memoization is a where we add caching to a function, to make recursive calls take less computations. typically used on recursive functions for a top down solution that starts with the initial problem and then recursively calls itself to smaller problems
2. tabulation uses a table to keep track of subproblem results and works up in bottom up manner, solving smallest sub problems before larger ones in a iterative manner.

Well my question is whats the difference? Sometimes I look at different situations and the line is super blurred. Also, with memoization working in a "top down" fashion, its really just referring to the stack nature of it, and in that sense its still going to the base case, aka bottom and then using those results to build up to the final result, so how is that really different from a tabulation going from bottom up until its done? Or is it a situational case where tabulation aproaches don't involve recursion, the fact that a dynmaic programming problem uses it IS what differentiates the two different methods? If someone knowledgable could offer there thoughts it would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You're right that they're just two implementation methods for the same computation. A recursive formulation with memoization will fill in the memo cache with the same entries that an explicit tabular formulation will put in its table.

Explicit tabular formulations are strictly less useful, however. This is because they need more information about the problem in advance. They start by enumerating all possibly useful base cases and putting those in the table. (So what's "possibly useful?" That's the rub!) Then they enumerate the new "layer" of all possible problem versions that can be solved with the base cases. Then a layer of others that can be solved with those, etc. etc. This continues  until it the "top level" problem turns up in a layer.

For the kinds of problems typically seen in textbooks and coding interviews, determining all useful base cases is deliberately easy. The problem parameters are 2 or 3 "dense" natural numbers, so the table of solutions can be a 2d or 3d array with all elements containing useful values. In many of these, you can prove that the current layer only depends on a few (possibly one) previous layer, so all the rest can be discarded, which saves memory.

Practical problems aren't often so nice. The parameter sets aren't small or aren't natural numbers, or - even when they are - they're sparse so that filling in all entries of an array would be a waste.

In these cases, memoization is the only reasonable choice. The top-down recursion determines the sub-problems (on down to the base cases) that need solving as they occur. Sparseness doesn't matter because the memo cache can store parameter sets as explicit keys. When the current layer doesn't need more than K previous ones, various strategies can still be applied to discard the others.